# Как увеличить кол-во ответов от github api?

Tags: api, github

Хочу получить ответ от апи с содержанием всех репозиториев с именем name
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=name&sort=stars&order=desc
но он отдает только 30. Как увеличить это количество до всех, что бы он отдавал все результаты.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Comment: так а если мне и надо сделать пагинацию на странице, мне же надо узнать общее количество записей, что бы отобразить нужное кол-во цифр на странице

Comment: По вашей же ссылке общее количество указано сразу же в самом верху

Comment: первый же элемент: total_count

Answer (score 0):

Одним запросом получить информацию о всех записях не получится, да в целом это и не правильно.

В запросе можно указать количество записей на страницу для этого необходимо добавить параметр `per_page`с указанием необходимого количества.

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=name&sort=stars&order=desc&&per_page=50
```

Через параметр `page` передается номер страницы.

Для получения всех записей нужно итерироваться по страницам пока есть результат.

---

[Документация](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/)